# Ubuntu restarts when I restore it from suspension

Tags: dual-boot, suspend

I have a problem when I suspend Ubuntu.
I have ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10 in dual boot.
When I suspend Ubuntu, it suspends normally, but when I restore it from suspension, it restarts. 
The same goes when I suspend Windows 10.

Can you help me?

Thanks!